# Using BLTouch on Y Axis instead of Z

Tags: g-code, bltouch

Long story short, Y and Z axis on my printer are swapped because it is a belt printer. Currently, the BLTouch sensor only works on Z axis, so I need to figure out how to do it for the Y axis otherwise I would need to design a limit switch sensor for the Y axis which in a conventional printer, would be height and would not be accurate. A software solution would be nice.

[Edited] Due to nature of slicer, its not possible to swap Y and Z motors.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Which firmare are you using? are you sure you cannot assign the BL touch to another axis? with Klipper the axis is not fixed and you can use it freely. Even if you cannot, maybe just swap the motor wires...

Comment: Thank you for your reply FarO. Swapping motors is not possible due to nature of the Slicer software. I will look at klipper as I have a raspberry pi. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I checked and I'm not sure Klipper works for other axes. Maybe you should open a ticket in the GitHub page. However klipper supports CoreXZ geometry, which may be of help in your case.